# Template for a heavily illustrated book

Tags: graphics

I'm writing a short maths book containing lots of pictures and illustrations. Can anyone suggest a suitable template for that purpose? Thanks.

Comment: What do you need the template to provide?

Comment: `\documentclass{book}` ?

Comment: `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `tikz` or `pstricks`?

Comment: There are ,many questions here regarding flowing text around images and tables.  Mixing pictures and equations is particularly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

`tufte-book` should work pretty well; it's pretty much meant for this sort of thing. Check out a sample of what it looks like [here](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf).

Comment: Although a bit late, many thanks! Pretty much the kind of thing I was looking for.